# How to get non focused recyclerview item using position android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I want to update the recyclerview adapter item's textview value dynamically with some data.

For that i'm doing this way:

```
View mRecyclerView = linearLayoutManager.getChildAt(viewPosition);

                TextView textView=(TextView) mRecyclerView.findViewById(R.id.text_number);
                Integer chatCount = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
                chatCount++;
                textView.setText(chatCount + "");
                jobsFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemChanged(viewPosition);
```

But the above coding is working only for visible views on the screen, For the views that are not visible i'm getting a null pointer exception for `mRecyclerView` can anyone help me on how to get the recyclerview item that is not in focus

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you should have an `adapter` that populates the data of the `RecyclerView`. That `adapter` has a method called `onBindViewHolder()` that populates each `ViewHolder`. That's where you should code how each `viewholder` should look.

For example: you could have a list of Strings (one for each viewholder). `onBindViewHolder` would take one `String` and set the `TextView` text as that String. So changing one String of that list (and calling `notifyItemChanged()`) would be enough

Comment: Thanks pelocho for responding, The solution you have provided is for initial setting up of data in adapter.but i what i want is to dynamically update the adapter item(exclusively) by giving its position to linearlayoutmanager(that is managing it) or recyclerview(that is holding) it .But all the methods getChildView(position) etc.. that are returning visible child. I want the the view that is not in focus by providing the index. I hope you have understood my question clearly

Comment: Yes, I did. The solution I gave works also for initial setting and updating items. Update the source of your data and call `notifyItemChanged()` (or `notifyDataSetChanged()` if you want to update everything)